# anksvn use branch for first time

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I want to be able to load my latest changes of visual studio 2008 into a branch of the latest version of anksvn.

To accomplish this goal, I would like to mention the following;

1. I want to create a 'branch' of the test code I am currently working with. Basically I have a folder structure that looks like the following: `program name/version 2.0/version 2.1`.
2. The production code is in the directory level `program name/version 2.0`. I want to put my 'test' code in a directory level `program name/version 2.0/version 2.1` that is I hope at the branch level.
3. When I try to use [Create a branch or tag](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/csvn/faq/whatiscollabnetsubversion.html), I get the message `path exists The branch/tag at URL already exists`.
4. When I look at [Switch to a branch](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/csvn/faq/whatiscollabnetsubversion.html),  I see the message,
   `Note: If you've made changes to your working copy but have not committed them yet, the changes will get merged when you switch.` I am afraid that my test code will get merged with the production code.
5. I have basically checked out code from the 'production' location in anksvn and have made changes to the code on my desktop. Now I want to be able to check in the new test code into a 'branch' of anksvn.

Thus can you tell me how to solve my problem? If I am not following the 'correct' procedures, can you tell me what I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not following *correct procedures* (I guess you wanted to say that you don't follow the standard svn layout: trunk/branches/tags), you have to create a new unique URL for your branch anyway (as I see you get *path exists* error in 3.). For example use  **/program name/version 2.0/version 2.1 test** and you will have the following layout:

```
program name/version 2.0/version 2.1/
                               code (production)
                        /version 2.1 test
                               code (with test changes)
```

The message (in 4.) about merging when switching to the branch is just a warning. In this case (according to 5.) the changes you have made will be merged locally after you will switch to the new branch in way as the original **program name/version 2.0/version 2.1/** is taken and then your local changes applied on top. So, you are right to enable this "Switch to Branch after creation" if you want to commit your changes to the newly created branch.

Comment: Can you tell me what the normal procedures are? I do not know that I was not following the 'normal' procedures? Should I be working with branches when adding code to an existing application?

Comment: It's better to say not "normal", but "recommended". You can find advice on that in a lot of books and articles: google for example for "SVN best practices". You can find some very basic things here: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/doc/user/svn-best-practices.html and http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/subversion_repo . For example, you can stick to "Branch when needed" workflow.

Comment: According to the recommended procedures, your version 2.0/2.1 should be either in /branches, but also maybe in /tags. What you need: is to discuss within the team of developers and agree when you do branches, when tags, i.e. define a formal procedures for delivery/integration which are out of scope of SVN.